# ng-model doesn't not work on input if value exist from beginning

Tags: angularjs

I am working on distribution software where as I am newbie to angular I got a trouble last day with ng-model I have several input fields and I am doing addition multiplication operations using ng-model it work fine till I enter the values but when I brought values in using ajax it left working and don't do the math operation.

For example : `product_rate` field , `pieces` field, `quantity` field and `amount` field.

```
<input id="rate_per_unit" name="rate_per_unit" ng-model="rate_per_unit" type="text" placeholder="0.00" required="required">

<input id="pcs" name="pcs" type="text" ng-model="quantity" placeholder="0" required="required">
<input id="quantity" name="quantity" value="{{ bonus -(-quantity) }}" type="text" placeholder="0" required="required">

<input id="amount" name="amount" value="{{ ((rate_per_unit * quantity) - cash_discount) -(-bonus * rate_per_unit) }}" type="text" placeholder="0.00%" required="required">
```

When user manually enter the values the math operation work fines but when I brought the value in rate_per_unit field and type directly in pieces field it stop the math operation in amount field.

What I want that the value exist in `rate_per_unit` field from before like following:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="rate_per_unit" value"1000">
```

And I just type in `pieces` field that do the multiplication operation here 
like i type 10 in pieces only and it start multiply with `rate_per_unit` field.

My markup with angular:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s2">
                        <input id="rate_per_unit" name="rate_per_unit" ng-model="rate_per_unit" type="text" placeholder="0.00" required="required">
                        <label for="contact">Rate Per Unit</label>   
                    </div>

                      <div class="input-field col s2">
                        <input id="pcs" name="pcs" type="text" ng-model="quantity" placeholder="0" required="required">
                        <label for="pcs">PCS</label>

                      </div>

                      <div class="input-field col s2">
                        <input id="quantity" name="quantity" value="{{ bonus -(-quantity) }}" type="text" placeholder="0" required="required">
                        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="input-field col s1">
                        <input id="bonus" name="bonus" type="text" ng-model="bonus" placeholder="0" required="required">
                        <label for="bonus">Bonus</label>
                      </div>


                      <div class="input-field col s2">
                        <input id="percent" name="percent" type="text" ng-model="percent" placeholder="0">
                        <label for="percent">Percent</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="input-field col s2">
                        <input id="percent_per_product" name="percent_per_product" type="text" placeholder="0">
                        <label for="percent_per_product">Percent per Product</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="input-field col s2">
                        <input id="discount" name="cash_discount" type="text" ng-model="cash_discount" placeholder="0">
                        <label for="discount">Cash Discount</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-field col s2">
                        <input id="amount" name="amount" value="{{ ((rate_per_unit * quantity) - cash_discount) -(-bonus * rate_per_unit) }}" type="text" placeholder="0.00%" required="required">
                        <label for="amount">Amount</label>
                      </div>

                    </div>
```

Here the ajax request for `rate_per_unit`

$("#product_id").on("select2:close",function() {

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'get_product_specification',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data:'id='+$(this).val(),
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('#rate_per_unit').val(data.trade_price);
      }
    });

    $('#rate_per_unit').focus();  
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you populate `rate_per_unit`?

Comment: You haven't shown your js code where you get value for `rate_per_unit`

Comment: I'm not clear with your question. From my understanding, you are populating the `rate_per_unit` from javascript and want the user to enter remaining values and compute the amount. Is it correct?

Comment: Why are you using an **input** field (i.e. something where the user is supposed to **enter** text) to produce an **output** (the result of a computation)? Also, you shouldn't use the `value` attribute of an input with ng-model: the whole point is that the value of the input is the value that is held in the variable referenced by ng-model.

Comment: sorry for late reply you mean the ajax request for rate_per_unit field which bring the data back

Comment: i have edited my question please check

Comment: i am getting value from database for `rate_per_unit` and i want that when user enter quantity it get multiply with `rate_per_unit` and show the result in amount field

Comment: Don't you have controller in place man. Just access the specific user model directly.  $scope.modelname = 1000.00; Computations can be done directly as well using the same. Please clearly in simple English tell me what you want and I will help you in very simple way. With Ajax and all you have confused me.

Comment: i have controller but i did it directly for avoiding the mess

Comment: Bro Controller is the essence of Angularjs. Ripe the benefits like two way binding and all.

Comment: i did it buddy the problem was with my logic i was injecting the value through ajax request and i wasnt putting the value in scope so that was the problem i am answering it shortly

Comment: @RanganathanSwamy u are right the controller is essence of Angular.js

Comment: I am glad you did it on your own. Keep up the good work.

Comment: @RanganathanSwamy you people made me do it..Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was i was injecting value to textbox via ajax request and weren't bounding that ng-model variable to scope of the controller and i was ignoring the whole stuff of angular controller and scope the very first important rule of angular is that dont go out of scope.

ng-model should remain in scope every value in or out should be bound with scope of the controller.

Before i was using ajax like that in my js file..

```
$("#product_id").on("select2:close",function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'get_product_specification',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data:'id='+$(this).val(),
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('#rate_per_unit').val(data.trade_price);
      }
    });

    $('#rate_per_unit').focus();  
});
```

it's wrong cause i am ignoring the ng-model variable of the text field i am just putting value in text field nothing else where as when we use ng-model variable we have to care about it scope.

The right way is .

```
$("#product_id").on("select2:close",function() {

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'get_product_specification',
        data:'id='+$(this).val(),
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
      }).success(function (data) {

       // show the value in textbox
        $('#rate_per_unit').val(data.trade_price);

          //Angular way of assigning value to ng-model variable
         $scope.rate_per_unit = data.trade_price;

      });

    $('#rate_per_unit').focus();  

  });
```

What happens here i attached the value to ng-model variable using scope service of angular so my mathematical computation start working cause my `rate_per_unit` has some value to compute it.